# Django : Is it impossible to static tag into block tag?

Tags: django, static, block

The code below makes error.. How could I resolve this problem?

```
{% block header %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'shop/style.css' %}" />
{% endblock %}
```

The error output:

> TemplateSyntaxError : Invalid block tag: 'static', expected 'endblock'

Comment: have you loaded `{% load staticfiles %}` ?

Comment: Ok, @nextdoordoc. Can you post your current template structure, please.

Comment: @karthikr is right and this is necessary even if your template inherits from a base.html file that already has the    {% load static %}    tag in it

Answer (score 163, accepted):

No, it is not impossible. Try including `{% load staticfiles%}` in the same html file, rather than attempting to inherit it from some `base.html`.

Comment: Does it mean that for every template I have to add this tag? This property does not get inherited in the child template?

Comment: Not a good option when extending from some `base.html` which wants to output all the static files right before the closing `</body>`, and when those static files may vary from page to page.

Comment: Thank you!I just solved my issue through your answer!

Comment: +1 for solution.  but it should include if we loaded static files in base. did not quite get the logic tho

Comment: Or you can just use `{% load static %}`, works as well.

Comment: Indeed, for future readers, since Django 1.10 the right way to serve static files it to use `{% load static %}`, `{% load staticfiles %}` is deprecated

Answer (score 21):

Just add `{% load static %}` to the top of your template *after* the `{% extends 'app/base.html' %}`.

Comment: This is the correct answer and it solves the problem. It should be marked accordingly.

Comment: @RokKlancar why? I want to include it in the base template, so that I only have to `{% load static %}` once. Not put it in every template file, that just sounds counter intuitive to the idea of code reusability, which is the point of the base template.

Comment: @ShanerM13 You are completley right. it is counter intuitive to the idea of code reusability. I don't know why this works as it does. You just have to put it in every template. Do not worry, though, the template inheritance still offers you plenty of benefits, so you don't really lose much, if you have to 'load static' every time

Comment: @RokKlancar yah, that was totally my thoughts, its just irritating... so I went through and did it... for... each... one...

Answer (score 12):

**1.) in settings.py add A TUPLE :**

STATIFILES_DIR = (
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'assets') ,
)

**2.) in urls.py add :**

```
 from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles.urlpatterns
 urlpatterns += staticfile_urlpatterns()
```

**3.) in the html file where you are putting the "link rel='stylesheet' .." , just add at the top :**

```
{% load static from staticfiles %}

 and then use :

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'assets/css' %}"
```

Answer (score 3):

My solution is to `include` another page with `{% load static %}` and script with static reference. `{% block xxx %}` expects the first `{% yyy %}` not to be other than `{% include %}` and `{% endblock %}`(the only cases I have observed); so when we use `"{% static 'xxx.js' %}"` it breaks and complains. But including another page will put Django in calm.

For example, I have a page `homepage` which extends `base.html` and has some static js files which are not included in `base.html`.

`base.html`

```
{% block page %}

{% endblock %}
{% block script %}

{% endblock %}
```

`homepage.html`:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block page %}
...
{% endblock %}
{% block script %}
    {% include 'home_js.html'%}  <!-- don't use static links here because Django does not like it. -->
{% endblock %}
```

`home_js.html`:

```
{% load static %}
<script src="{% static 'scripts/jquery.js' %}" ></script>
<script>
    function ...
</script>
```

Now the scripts loads.

So, in a block we cannot use `{% %}` tags other than `{% block xxx %}` and `{% endblock %}`.

I am using Django 5.1.

EDIT:

I found `{% verbatim %}` tag to be our savior under such situation.

Comment: Super useful {% verbatim %}, I didn't know the existance of it. Thanks

Comment: @WesternGun, how does `{% verbatim %}` help with this -- e.g. unable to use `{% load static %}` within a block?

Comment: I didn't remember sorry, was long time ago.

Answer (score -1):

If you are you are using Apache, make sure you have configured the virtual host to serve static files,  for example in `000-default.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    Alias /static /home/Dev/cfehome/src/static
        <Directory /home/Dev/cfehome/src/static>
           Require all granted
         </Directory>

    <Directory /home/Dev/cfehome/src/cfehome>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    WSGIDaemonProcess cfehome python-path=/home/Dev/cfehome/src:/home/Dev/cfehome/lib/python3.7/site-packages
    WSGIProcessGroup cfehome
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/Dev/cfehome/src/cfehome/wsgi.py


    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score -2):

Yes. Django won't allow it.

You can just use the appropriate path like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/shop/style.css" />
```

But be aware: If you change your app's `STATIC_URL`, the `href` above must also be updated accordingly.

From **[Configuring static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/#configuring-static-files)**:

> In your templates, either hardcode the url like /static/my_app/example.jpg or, preferably, use the static template tag...