# Django Is it possible to write text outside block in child template

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-staticfiles

I am trying to do the following

```
{% block csslinks %} 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'hello/style.css' %}">
{% endblock %}
```

I know it is impossible, but what are the alternatives? The was a similar question at [Django : Is it impossible to static tag into block tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22650371/django-is-it-impossible-to-static-tag-into-block-tag)

I was suggested there to `{% load staticfiles %}` didn`t answer what to write here?

```
{% block csslinks %} 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="what to write here to include css?">
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: *What* is impossible, and what does this have to do with text outside blocks?

Answer (score 2):

I dont have any problem with

```
{% block csslinks %} 
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'hello/style.css' %}">
{% endblock %}
```

so long as `{% load staticfiles %}` is on the top of the same template..