# Can not nest {% static %} tag under if block in Django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I get `Invalid block tag: 'static', expected 'endif'` when I render the following template

```
{% load staticfiles %} <!-- in base.html -->/
 <!-- ... -->
{% block content %}
    {% if ava_url %}
        <div><img src="{{ava_url}}"></div>
    {% else %}
        <div><img src="{% static 'img/default_ava.png' %}"></div>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Why cannot I nest `static` under `if`?

Using Django 1.6.7

**upd** This is all in block container. Might be the reason. However when I remove `if`

```
{% load staticfiles %}  <!-- in base.html -->
 <!-- ... -->
{% block content %}

    <div><img src="{% static 'img/default_ava.png' %}"></div>

{% endblock %}
```

I get `Invalid block tag: 'static', expected 'endblock'`

**upd** solved. included `{% load staticfiles%}` in derived template. Sorry, it was not obvious, that `{% load staticfiles%}` was in base template in the first place. The answer was found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22650371/django-is-it-impossible-to-static-tag-into-block-tag)

However I need further explanation: why `{% load staticfiles%}` does not work from base template?

Comment: What is your Django version?

Comment: django version 1.6.7

Comment: Did you add django.contrib.staticfiles to installed apps?

Comment: yes, I did. Templates work fine apart from this case.

Comment: can you verify to see if there are no syntax errors in the base template? also, do you face this issue if you call this templatetag outside the `if` block ?

Comment: updated to answer. base template appears to work fine if I delete `static` tag

Comment: Have you tried: `{% load static from staticfiles %}` ?

Comment: Just have tried. Did not help, unfortunately.

Comment: solved. Just wrote `load static` in the same file rather than in base one. But why `{% load staticfiles%}` does not work from base template?

Comment: Template tags only work on the template they are inherited in. They don't "trickle down" in scope to child templates.

Comment: `load static` is the proper syntax/call and as others have said, has to be called in each template that it is used; included templates can `load` their own tags

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Think of it like an import statement where the base template is a function within one module that is calling a function in another module, the derived template, with some parameters.

The "import" in the base template doesn't get inherited by the derived template and thus it needs to be "imported" with `{% load ... %}`